# Avoid resizing CSS background image with mobile keyboard

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile

I've configured a full screen background image with CSS like this:

```
html {
    background: url(image url) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When I first open the site in a mobile browser it looks great. However, if I select a form input and the mobile keyboard pops open then the background image resizes to match the height of the view that's above the keyboard.

Is there any way to keep the height of the background image static when the mobile keyboard opens? CSS only solutions are preferred.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of what the backround looks like when you focus on the input? Also, what os/os version are you testing on?

Comment: Also, does it resize to fit within the viewport of the window/keyboard (creating a "squashed" image) or does it scale up in size?

Comment: I've been testing on chrome and firefox mobile versions, as well as the chrome dev-tools mobile view. It resizes to fit into the viewport of the window/keyboard. I think the problem is that `background-size: cover` resizes the image to fit the viewport. I've started to manually tweak the background size in media queries to "zoom in" on it to make it appear similar to the non-keyboard view. This causes jumps though and I'm not confident I'm going to be able to test every device size

Comment: If anyone is curious this article does a good job discussing the difficulties of handling viewport resizing with mobile keyboards - https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/toolbars-keyboards-and-the-viewports-10abcc6c3769

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am having the same issue..

Comment: Unfortunately I did not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve this with CSS variables. First add this to your `<head>`:

```html
<script>document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--original-viewport-height', window.innerHeight+"px")</script>
```

Now you can set the `min-height` of your background element to `var(--original-viewport-height)`.

Here's an example of the code that I'm using:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
body::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url(img.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: var(--original-viewport-height);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  will-change: transform;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

(As you can see, in my specific case the background is on the `::before` rather than directly on the body to solve [the jittery scrolling issue](https://www.blindemanwebsites.com/today-i-learned/2020/jittery-scrolling/) with *fixed* backgrounds in Android Chrome.)

Comment: It's been so long I unfortunately don't have access to reproduce this issue and test the solution, but thank you for the insightful response! Seems like it should work, so marking this solved